# How to solve one to many relation tables foreign key field empty?

Tags: entity

I write this code but table relations **one to many**.So Person is add tables.But PersonFamily tables relations.The table is a table associated with the PersonFamily table.The code in this case works. But when I add into the PersonFamily table with ToList, the PersonFamily table data is multiplying.

Person family is taking data from two database.I want that personfamily come without data.(PersonFamily come empty.)

How can I set the StudentFamily table to come from the beginning?

How to make a clear personFamily table?

```
var listPerson = new List<PERSON>();
using (var t = DbContext.SingleInstance().Entities)
{
    listPerson.AddRange(t.PERSON);
}

using(var personInformation=DbContext.SingleInstance().TKEntities)
{
    foreach(var p in listPerson)
    {
        personInformation.PERSON.Add(p);
    }
    personInformation.SaveChanges();
}


PERSON TABLE : PersonID,NAME,SURNAME,PERSONFAMILYID,PERSONCOURSEID

PERSONFAMILY TABLE:PersonID,PERSONFAMILYID,PERSONFAMILYNAME,PERSONFAMILYSURNAME

PERSONCOURSE TABLE: PERSONID,COURSEID,COURSENAME

PERSONTABLE-PERSONFAMILY IS ONE TO MANY

PERSONTABLE-PERSONCOURSE IS ONE TO MANY.
```

I want to get PersonFamily table is empty.

Comment: Could you please re-phrase the question as it's not clear what the desired behavior is? A database diagram would help a lot!

Comment: Hi.I edit question and I write tables.Thank you.